# How to get class name from callable that is from runnable

Tags: java, spring, runnable, java.util.concurrent, callable

So i have this piece of code

```
    @Bean
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(50);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(5000);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("sm-async-");
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.initialize();
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler((r, executor1) -> {
            int i = 0;
        });
        return executor;
    }
```

What i want to do is i want to get the name of the class inside the argument([see the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XEYb.png)). My objective is to get the class name that has been rejected and report it for monitoring purposes. Im stuck on how to get the name. This is spring project

Answer (score 1):

You can try 'Field' property. Java accesible objects has a functions for get sub fields. When you use the field object and get method, you will have an array for all declared fields. You can find more detail in [Java Get Declared Fields](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getdeclaredfields.htm). This property can reach variables or sub classes.